# Where trailing return type is actually needed in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am reading about trailing return type. I came across this site https://blog.petrzemek.net/2017/01/17/pros-and-cons-of-alternative-function-syntax-in-cpp/ which is explaining about the need of these return types and it mentioned as below.

> ```
> template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
> decltype(lhs + rhs) add(const Lhs& lhs, const Rhs& rhs) {
>     // error: ^^^ 'lhs' and 'rhs' were not declared in this scope
>     return lhs + rhs;
> }
> ```
>
> ... Since the compiler parses the source code from left to right, it sees lhs and rhs before their definitions, and rejects the code. By using the trailing return type, we can circumvent this limitation.

But as per my understanding, by the time compiler reaches decltype(lhs + rhs), it should already know the types of lhs and rhs. Can any one please let me know why compiler is not able to deduce the return types of the function and are there any other uses where we must use trailing return type other than templates.

Comment: "as per my understanding, ..." Can you please clarify why you think the compiler should know the types?

Comment: Compiler should see template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs> by the time it reaches decltype().

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your question; it seems the answer is in the quoted text? "Since the compiler parses the source code from left to right, it sees lhs and rhs before their definitions, and rejects the code." Note the types start with capital letters there and the variable names start with lowercase.

Comment: @kadina the compiler knows the *types* in the `template`, but it does not know the *variables* that are mentioned in the `decltype`, because they haven't been declared yet. So it doesn't know the types involved in the `operator+`. Maybe `Lhs` implements `operator+` differently than `Rhs` does, the compiler doesn't know until it sees the declarations to know which types are actually involved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It knows the capitalized types `Lhs` and `Rhs`, but not the lowercase variables `lhs` and `rhs`. They're declared after the `decltype`.